# two LocalDateTime variables arent compared properly?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a method that pick up the records ( named runtime ) from the SQL database connected with hibernate. The problem comes when i want to filter the results by the date. I declared the variable with the date from which i want to see the results, but it never goes through the 'if' statement. In Debugger i see that these two dates to compare are with the same format, i dont know why doesnt it work. Any ideas?

i attach the screens with the debugger status of variables, the problem comes where i check if -> runtime.getDateTime is after 'reportDateFrom' variable.

debugger variable status - > https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/64350066_418943105623455_284358622048157696_n.png?_nc_cat=110&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.xx&oh=a2ff24ad936bc2843658afe9dc130128&oe=5D881E1E

method -> https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/64673116_2354086638248857_6383211241770319872_n.png?_nc_cat=111&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.xx&oh=7207d510996b24f54235adcc76de7100&oe=5D7B4FE6

```
public int getUpTimeInMinutes(String machineName) {
    machineName = "4x2 brick mould";
    List<Runtime> runTime = runtimeRepository.findAllByMachineName(machineName);
    LocalDateTime reportDateFrom = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0);
    // Method will calculate the difference between the two records when the machine had the isRunning =1 and 0
    String previousRecordTime = null;
    String actualRecordTime;
    int minutesUptime = 0;
    for (Runtime runtime : runTime) {
        // first i filter from the date requested
        if (runtime.getDatetime().isAfter(reportDateFrom)) {
            if (runtime.getIsRunning() == 1) {
                // below i save the record where machine started working and convert it first to LocalTime and then to String of format HH:mm
                previousRecordTime = runtime.getDatetime().toLocalTime().toString();
            } else if (runtime.getIsRunning() == 0) {
                // below i save the date where machine stopped working and calculate the difference between the two records using another method
                actualRecordTime = runtime.getDatetime().toLocalTime().toString();
                minutesUptime += calculateDifferenceBetweenStrings(previousRecordTime, actualRecordTime);
            }
        }
    }
    return minutesUptime;
}
```

Comment: So 2018 is not after 2019.

Comment: i guess its easy to see im a junior :)